# using process explorer to "debug" powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, process-explorer

i'm frequently using process explorer from sysinternals to "debug" some problems with applications, eg network connection issues.

For example, i start an exe applications which drops an error-message "could not connect" or something. i use process-explorer (TCP-TAB) to figure out to which address the app wants to connect and which port, this information will be shown in the tcp-tab of process explorer. so far so good.

i try to do the same with a powershell-script. 
so i am focusing on the powershell window and open the tcp-TAB, but nothing shows up there. no tcp-connection attempts.

i do a

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "www.google.de" -Port 80
```

in a loop so it should show up there.
how can i use process-explorer to see outgoing connections from a powershell script?

best regards
paul

Comment: process explorer is unlikely to show a TCP connection that doesn't last at least 1 second. perhaps procmon is a better fit for your needs, since it logs and you can review it afterward.

Comment: TCPView may also be a good choice. it shows connections for at least 2 seconds, first in Green, and then in Red as they are closed out. you can filter by PID or exe name to make sure you can find the connections.

Comment: i could handle it. The powershell was running priviledged as admin, therefore a new process is spawning. keeping an eye on that process solves the issue.